# unable to send variable value into function

Tags: html, angular, drop-down-menu

```
        <li ngbDropdown="" class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a ngbDropdownToggle="" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="javascript:;" id="bydate" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
            aria-expanded="false">
          <i class="icofont icofont-bank-alt"></i> All</a>
          <div ngbDropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="bydate">
            <a class="dropdown-item" value="all" (click)="setCategory('all')">All</a>
            <div *ngFor="let category of categories">
            <a class="dropdown-item" [ngClass]="category.selected"  value="category" (click)="setCategory(catergory);">{{category}}</a>
          </div>
          </div>
        </li>
```

I am trying to send a value of category, on change of dropdown value into setCategory() function, but I am getting the value as undefined.

Comment: You have a typo in your code , “category” and not “catergory”

Comment: yes thank you so much, one more query, I want the selected category to be shown in the drop-down, instead of default name 'all'.